# Sql regexp that accepts chinese character,ascii & rejects special characters

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I need a sql regexp pattern that satisfied the following criteria.

1.Accepts chinese characters,
2.Accepts - a-z,A-Z,0-9,spaces
3.Rejects only special characters.

I've tried the following.

```
  Select regexp_like((val)::TEXT , ('^[ !-’~¡-ÿ]*$')::TEXT)


      Or
```

regexp_like((val)::TEXT ,('^[^[:ascii:]]+$')::text);

The above query also accepts special characters it should not be.

SELECT (('#$$')::TEXT ~ ('^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$'));

This query satisfied but fails to accept chinese character.

Comment: Which characters should it reject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the unicode values of the chinese characters

```
SELECT (('#$$')::TEXT ~ ('^[a-zA-Z0-9\x4e00-\x9fff\x3400-\x4dbf]*$'));
```

Comment: good accept the answer then

Comment: i want to include special characters.@nbk

Comment: our questio was about rejecting special characters but then add them to the regex `'^[a-zA-Z0-9&%$§\x2345`\x4e00-\x9fff\x3400-\x4dbf]*$'`  if you want more, ou add almost anything character as unicode `\x2345` see the string abouve.#

Answer (score 0):

According to *Wikipedia*, the Chinese characters are within the following Unicode range, U+4E00, through U+9FFF.  *[Wikipedia – CJK Unified Ideographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_blocks)*.

Additionally, there are *Extensions A through H*.
*[CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_A)*, U+3400 through U+4DBF.
*[CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_B)*, U+20000 through U+2A6DF.
*[CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_C)*, U+2A700 through U+2B73F.
*[CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_D)*, U+2B740 though U+2B81F.
*[CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_E)*, U+2B820 though U+2CEAF.
*[CJK Unified Ideographs Extension F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_F)*, U+2CEB0 through U+2EBEF.
*[CJK Unified Ideographs Extension G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_G)*, U+30000 through U+3134F.
*[CJK Unified Ideographs Extension H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_H)*, U+31350 through U+323AF.

So, you can add a Unicode range to your character class, as follows.

> *"1.Accepts chinese characters"*

```
[\u4e00-\u9fff]
```

> *"2.Accepts - a-z,A-Z,0-9,spaces"*

The *(?i)*, will toggle-on *case-insensitive* mode.

```
(?i)[a-z\d \u4e00-\u9fff]
```

> *"3.Rejects only special characters."*

I imagine the values you provided, are the characters you wish to reject.
For the provided range, *! through ’*, you want to skip over the digit characters, *0 through 9*, and the uppercase letters, *A through Z*.

So, that will need to be changed to the following.

```
[^!-/:-@\[-`~¡-ÿ]
```

You can then add this character class to the previous, using the *character class intersection* syntax, *&&*.

So, the complete pattern would be the following.

```
(?i)^[a-z\d \u4e00-\u9fff&&[^!-/:-@\[-`~¡-ÿ]]*$
```

Comment: this is not correct as ou have missed a lot of characters

Comment: @nbk, it looks like there there are extension blocks A through H.  Should these ranges be added?  I see in your answer you only included block A.

Comment: @Hoper, no problem, glad it helped.  It looks like there are additional ranges that can be added.  They are specified within the _Wikipedia_ article I linked, if you'd like to review them.